# How can I access array built in useEffect hook with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using useEffect to make 2 requests to 2 different API's. I'm building an array based on the info that's getting returned. I'd like to access this array outside of useEffect and use it in the return below, where I want to use the data to render points on a map. When I try to access it, like how I'm using `parkData` it says `all_data` is not defined.

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import * as parkData from "./data/skateboard-parks.json";
import "./App.css";
import axios from 'axios';

let all_info = []

export default function App() {

    const validator_url = "http://api-1.com"
    const ip_url = "http://ip-api.com/json/"
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const result1 = await axios.get(validator_url);

        for (let i = 0; i < result1.data.count; i+=1) {
          const result2 = await axios.get(`${ip_url}${result1.data.results[i].ip_address}`);

          let ip_address = result1.data.results[i].ip_address
          let lat = result2.data.lat
          let lon = result2.data.lon

          all_info.push([ip_address, lat, lon])
        }
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[45.4, -75.7]} zoom={12}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {/* // HOW CAN I ACCESS all_info ARRAY HERE instead of using parkData? */}
      {parkData.features.map(park => (
        <Marker key={park.properties.PARK_ID} position={[park.geometry.coordinates[1], park.geometry.coordinates[0]]}>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Store it as state. Side note: You probably want to handle errors from that `fetchData` fucntion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to store that data in the internal state of the component instead of the global variable.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import * as parkData from "./data/skateboard-parks.json";
import "./App.css";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
    const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState([]);
    const validator_url = "http://api-1.com"
    const ip_url = "http://ip-api.com/json/"
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const result1 = await axios.get(validator_url);
        const tempData = []

        for (let i = 0; i < result1.data.count; i+=1) {
          const result2 = await axios.get(`${ip_url}${result1.data.results[i].ip_address}`);

          let ip_address = result1.data.results[i].ip_address
          let lat = result2.data.lat
          let lon = result2.data.lon

          tempData.push([ip_address, lat, lon])
        }
        setAllInfo(tempData);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[45.4, -75.7]} zoom={12}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {/* // HOW CAN I ACCESS all_info ARRAY HERE instead of using parkData? */}
      {parkData.features.map(park => (
        <Marker key={park.properties.PARK_ID} position={[park.geometry.coordinates[1], park.geometry.coordinates[0]]}>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
{all_info?all_info.features.map(all_info => (
// your code
        
)):null}
```

Comment: Also use useState for storing the data ,like people have mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

Create a state using `useState` hook to store the array and use that rather than defining the array outside the function.

```js
export default function App() {
    const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = React.useState([]);
    
    const validator_url = "http://api-1.com"
    const ip_url = "http://ip-api.com/json/"
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const result1 = await axios.get(validator_url);
        const data = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < result1.data.count; i+=1) {
          const result2 = await axios.get(`${ip_url}${result1.data.results[i].ip_address}`);

          let ip_address = result1.data.results[i].ip_address
          let lat = result2.data.lat
          let lon = result2.data.lon

          data.push([ip_address, lat, lon]);
        }

        setAllData(prevState => [...prevState, data]);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);
    ...
    }
```